# Least Square Fitting Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, least-squares, data-fitting

I am writing an algorithm in Python to fit a data (I need to write my own algorithm). But I have a problem with the arrays. For example:

```
import math
x=[2,1]
a=sum([x[i]*x[i] for i in range(len(x))])
```

It is working. However when I tried to divide, it is not working.

```
import math
x=[2,1,5]
y=[3,2,5]
a=sum(([y[i]*y[i] for i in range(len(x))])/([x[i]*x[i] for i in range(len(x))]))
```

How can I fix it? Do you have any idea?

Comment: why do you have two times `for i ` and what's the error

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: import math
x=[2,1]
a=1/sum([x[i]*x[i] for i in range(len(x))]) is also not working. @user1767754

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'generator' is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on your code I believe that your goal is to divide every element of the y list by every element of the x list and then sum them, if that is the case, I would write something like that:

```
import math
x=[2,1,5]
y=[3,2,5]

a = sum([yy / xx for yy, xx in zip(y, x)])
```

You just iterate throught the zipped lists and divide each element from y by corresponding element from x.
In your code you are trying to divide list by a list, which is not a supported operation, so thats why you get the error.